# How can I load a local html page on chromium in Incognito mode?

Tags: command-line, chromium

Does anyone know how to load a local html page on chromium in incognito mode using a shortcut link or by the terminal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and run the below command, change the url accordingly.

```
chromium-browser --incognito file:///home/srinivas/example-page.html
```

To make things easy you can put the code in a text file and save it with a **.sh** extension.

Once its saved right click on the file, navigate to the permission tab and check mark

`allow executing file as program`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in the terminal:

```
chromium-browser --incognito <path-to-file>
```

A picture example after running the command above on a html page I saved online (this page actually):

[image]